# Does simulating memory-mapped I/O using VMX require instruction decoding?

Tags: memory, assembly, virtualization

I am wondering how a hypervisor using Intel's VMX / VT technology would simulate memory-mapped I/O (so that the guest could think it was performing memory mapped I/O againsta  device).

I think the basic principle would be to set up the EPT page tables in such a way that the memory addresses in question would cause an EPT violation (i.e. VM exit) by setting them such that they cannot be read or written? However, the next question is how to process the VM exit. Such a VM-exit would fill out all the exit qualification reasons etc. including the guest-linear and guest-physical address etc. But what I am missing in these exit qualification fields is some field indicating - in case of a write instruction - the value that was attempted to be written and the size of the write. Likewise, for a read instruction it would be nice with some bit fields indicating the destination of the read, say a register or a memory location (in case of memory-to-memory string operations). This would make it very easy for the hypervisor to figure out what the guest was trying to do and then simulate the device behavior towards the guest.

But the trouble is, I can't find such fields among the exit qualifications. I can see an instruction pointer to where the faulting instruction is, so I could walk the page tables to read in the instruction and then decode it to understand the instruction, then simulate the I/O behavior. However, this requires the hypervisor to have a fairly complete picture of all x86 instructions, and be able to decode them. That seems to be quite a heavy burden on the hypervisor, and will also require it to stay current with later instruction additions. And the CPU should already have this information.

There's a chance that that I am missing these relevant fields because the documentation is quite extensive, but I have tried to search carefully but have not been able to find it. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction OR confirm that the hypervisor will need to contain an instruction decoder.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You may want to check [VT-d](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-specifications/vt-directed-io-spec.pdf) paper from Intel though, as it deals with IO virtualization

Comment: It would *significantly* help readability if you broke that giant wall of text up into multiple paragraphs.

Comment: Interesting title, but not interesting enough to wade through this giant single-paragraph wall of text.

Comment: @Peter: I have inserted some breaks if that is what you were referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most VMs decode the instruction. It's not actually that hard, and most VMs have software emulators to fallback on when the CPU VM extensions aren't available or up to the task. You don't need to handle every instruction, just those that can take memory operands, and you can probably ignore everything that isn't a 1, 2, or 4 byte memory operand since you're not likely to emulating device registers other than those sizes. (For memory mapped device buffers, like video memory, you don't want to be trapping every memory accesses because that's too slow, and so you'll have to take different approach.)

However, there is one way you can let the CPU do the work for you, but it's much slower then decoding the instruction itself and it's not entirely perfect. You can single step the instruction while temporarily mapping in a valid page of RAM. The VM exit will tell you the guest physical address access and whether it was a read or write. Unfortunately it doesn't reliably tell you whether it was read-modify-write instruction, those may just set the write flag, and with some device registers that can make a difference. It might be easier to copy the instruction (it can only be a most 15 bytes, but watch out for page boundaries) and execute it in the host, but that requires that you can map the page to same virtual address in the host as in the guest.

You could combine these techniques, decode the common instructions that are actually used to access memory mapped device registers, while using single stepping for the instructions you don't recognize.

Note that by choosing to write your own hypervisor you've put a heavy burden on yourself. Having to decode instructions in software is a pretty minor burden compared to the task of emulating an entire IBM PC compatible computer. The Intel virtualisation extensions aren't designed to make this easier, they're just designed to make it more efficient. It would be easier to write a pure software emulator that interpreted the instructions. Handling memory mapped I/O would be just a matter of dispatching the reads and writes to the correct function.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks I appreciate the answer. And it is also in line with what I feared/expected. I am really wondering why Intel didn't implement this functionality. The software decoding must also incur an overhead, and CPU has a dedicated HW decoder. It would just be a matter of putting some of the control signals into the VM registers and it would generalize across all instruction classes. I see your point about VMX not being about making it easier to write a hypervisor (but to make it more efficient).

Comment: ...However, I did read articles saying the first versions of VMX were actually slower than a SW emulator, but it made writing the hypervisor simpler. By the way, in my case it would make a huge difference. I don't need to virtualize all aspects of the IBM PC so the VMExit handlers etc. will be a significant amount of the work. But this gets much more complicated by throwing a full instruction decoder (and to a large extent also emulator) into the mix. And raises the question about later instruction additions etc. I like your idea about swapping in a page though I agree it sounds like it...

Comment: ... it might inefficient. It really would be much cleaner with the CPU helping a bit. AMD has a feature called "decode assists" but as far as I can tell from documentation it basically provides the same info as Intel, it doesn't seem to provide the extra info I am asking about.

Comment: BTW I think an essentially full decoder+emulator (which seems to be required) IS a significant amount of work even when compared to a "somewhat full" emulation of IBM PC HW (PIC+PIT+VGA+keyboard etc.). Because these hardware units are old and quite simple, and for providing the actual service the hypervisor can use the host OS functions so it is just a mapping and not implementation of functionality. Whereas for the instructions you have to fully implement a host of prefixes, encodings, CPU modes and instruction set extensions and almost all combinations thereof.

Comment: @Morty As I said, you don't need a full instruction decoder. Only a small subset of instructions are actually used to access memory mapped device registers. You don't have to worry about stack, FPU, SIMD or system instructions, especially those that don't match the size of register since what happens then isn't well defined. If you crash the VM because a RET, FLD, MOVSD, or SGDT instruction accessed device memory it'll be the right thing to do because the VM is executing garbage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in details how VT-X works, but I think I see a flaw in your wishlist way it could work:

Remember that x86 is not a load/store machine.  **The load part of `add [rdi], 2` doesn't have an architecturally-visible destination**, so your proposed solution of telling the hypervisor where to find or put the data doesn't really work, unless there's some temporary location that isn't part of the guest's architectural state, used only for communication between the hypervisor and the VMX hardware.

To handle a read-modify-write instruction with a memory destination efficiently, the VM should do the whole thing with one VM exit.  So you can't just provide separate load and store interfaces.

More importantly, handling atomic read-modify-writes is a special case.  `lock add [rdi], 2` can't just be done as a separate load and store.

Comment: Hi Peter, yes I see your point about read-modify-write, as you point out it would require a communication field in VMCS and potentially two VMExit's. The extra VMExit surely adds overhead but that is also true of the decoding/emulation. Also the current solution has overhead related to the HVM having to manually wal the page tables of the guest just to get the instruction bytes, next having to walk them to get the data value (to be read) and to manually handle all the page-table logic without TLB's or any of that sort. Given how common MMIO is a lot of cycles must be wasted on this.

Comment: I am looking through the "emulate.c" file from KVM which is the file in KVM that seems to do the job. And while it does seem to cover many instruction types there are also many it doesn't. For instance, I see no attempt at emulating SSE instructions. Does this mean that if I write an o/s with a driver that attempts to do memory-mapped I/O using a new and shiny SSE instruction, it won't work?

Comment: @Morty: IDK, interesting question about SSE in KVM.  MOVNT stores are potentially useful for writing to cacheable device memory, since they evict the data from the CPU's cache.

Comment: @Morty: Do some HVMs keep emulating for a few instructions, since it's probably common for MMIO stores to come in groups?  That would let them reuse the results of the software page-walk for multiple I/O operations.  Like I said, I don't know much about VM implementation; I only posted this as an answer because comments aren't big enough.